# Java Параллельное программирование В матрице отобразить симметрично относительно ветрикальной оси сектора

Tags: java, матрицы, распараллеливание, задание-на-собеседовании

В матрице нужно отобразить симметрично относительно вертикальной оси сектора, которые лежат правее и левее главной и побочной диагонали. Все это нужно сделать с применением параллелизма на Java

[image: стрелкой указаны сектора, которые нужно поменять между собой]

Comment: А проблема/вопрос в чём? Как вы пытались решить данную задачу, и с чем именно у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: Трудности со всем. Тяжело представляю как можно сделать это в несколько потоков

Comment: Уважаемый kff, Вы вполне возможно правы, но надежда умирает последней. Иногда люди просто берут и помогают, вот чудо. Имею смелость понадеяться

Comment: @KristinaKuli Я не думаю, что так уж сложно выразить принятую на данном сайте благодарность, нажав на зелёную галочку. Люди действительно часто просто помогают, но если за их помощь они перестают получать даже элементарное "спасибо", желание помогать может пройти. Поэтому я предлагаю не уменьшать число желающих помочь. ;)

Comment: @kff, согласна с Вами,  поблагодарила Вас за предыдущую помощь в решении проблемы с JavaScript. Но все это совершенно не относится к текущему вопросу

Comment: @KristinaKuli надеяться - это здорово, но вы могли бы хотя бы добавить в вопрос код создания матрицы, а также пример (начальное и конечные состояния матрицы)

Comment: кстати, а зачем _физически_ менять элементы в массиве? можно же просто подставлять индексы при обращении

Comment: Распишите, пожалуйста, задачу поконкретней. То ли вечер то ли фраза "левее и правее главной и побочной диагонали" вводит меня в ступор, так как есть только над и под диагональю и на самой диагонали, справа или слева нет. Еще и вопрос в фразе отобразить симметрично относительно вертикальной оси....

Comment: @KristinaKuli советую переформулировать задание, тогда вам помогут

Comment: Все такие щедрые на советы, как будто мы в анекдоте про Страну Советов. :)

Answer (score 1):

Квадратная матрица

> A(1,1) A(1,2) A(1,3)
>
> A(2,1) A(2,2) A(2,3)
>
> A(3,1) A(3,2) A(3,3)

---

A(i,j) - значение элемента матрицы

> А - имя матрицы
>
> i - номер строки
>
> j - номер столбца

---

Главная диагональ - от верхнего левого угла в нижний правый угол.
Побочная диагональ - от правого верхнего угла в левый нижний угол.

---

Соотношение индексов в квадратной матрице

```
i<j       элементы матрицы находятся над главной диагональю
i>j       элементы матрицы находятся под главной диагональю
i+j<n+1   элементы матрицы находятся над побочной диагональю
i+j>n+1   элементы матрицы находятся под побочной диагональю
// то что нужно исключить
i+j=n+1   элементы матрицы находятся на побочной диагонали
i=j       элементы матрицы находятся на главной диагонали
```

---

Исходя их этих данных вы теперь будете знать какие сектора(элементы массива) находятся над и под главной и побочной диагоналями.

```
public class MyTest {

@Test
public void runTest() {

    int length = 9;

    int n = length - 2;

    int[][] underMain = new int[length][length];
    int[][] aboveMain = new int[length][length];

    int[][] underSecond = new int[length][length];
    int[][] aboveSecond = new int[length][length];

    int[][] arr = new int[length][length];

    fill(arr, 8, length);


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (i < j) {
                aboveMain[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }
            if (i > j) {
                underMain[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }
            if (i + j < n + 1) {
                aboveSecond[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }
            if (i + j > n + 1) {
                underSecond[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    niceView(underMain);
    niceView(aboveMain);
    niceView(underSecond);
    niceView(aboveSecond);

}

// метод для вывода в консоль
public void niceView(int[][] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("[%d]", array[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//Метод для заполнения массива 
public void fill(int[][] a, int val, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Продолжение с параллелизмом только после уточнения вопроса.....

Comment: И где здесь требуемый параллелизм?

Comment: Будет конкретизирован вопрос - будет ответ с параллелизмом.
На данный момент могу только предполагать что его использовать нужно будет для того чтобы "отобразить симметрично относительно вертикальной оси". 
А здесь просто негде, а создавать 4 потока и загонять туда цикл for с if для каждого случая - конечно можно, но глупо, так как не принесет никакого прироста  в производительности.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге, я подумала и вот что написала. В два потока, переворачивает нужные сектора.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab1 {

public static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10000;
public static final int THREADS_COUNT = 2;


public static void generateArr(int arr[][]) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        for(int j=0;j < arr[i].length; j++){
            arr[i][j] = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);

        }

    }
}

public static void printArr(int arr[][]) {
    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        for(int j=0;j < arr[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public static void transformArr(int arr[][], int from, int to) {

    for(int j=0; j< arr.length/2; j++){
        for(int i=from;i <to ; i++){
            if ((i!=j)&&((j)!=(arr.length-1-i)) ){

                int t = arr[i][arr.length-1-j];
                arr[i][arr.length-1-j] =arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j] = t;

            }
        }

    }
}


static class MatrixTransformationThread extends Thread{
    private int arr[][];
    private int from;
    private int to;


    MatrixTransformationThread(int[][] arr, int from, int to) {
        super();
        this.arr = arr;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int j=0; j< arr.length/2; j++){
            for(int i=from;i <to ; i++){
                if ((i!=j)&&((j)!=(arr.length-1-i)) ){

                    int t = arr[i][arr.length-1-j];
                    arr[i][arr.length-1-j] =arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j] = t;

                }
            }

        }
    }


}




public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    int array[][] = new int[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];



   generateArr(array);


    long startTimeSimple = System.nanoTime();
   transformArr(array,1,(array.length-1)/2);
   transformArr(array,(array.length-1)/2,(array.length-1));
    long elapsedTimeSimple = System.nanoTime() - startTimeSimple;
    System.out.println(elapsedTimeSimple);



    MatrixTransformationThread [] threads = new MatrixTransformationThread[THREADS_COUNT];
    long startTimeThread = System.nanoTime();
    threads[0] = new MatrixTransformationThread(array ,  1 , (array.length-1)/2 );
    threads[1] = new MatrixTransformationThread(array,(array.length-1)/2,(array.length-1));
    threads[0].start();
    threads[1].start();

    for( Thread th : threads ){
        th.join();
    }
    long elapsedTimeThread = System.nanoTime() - startTimeThread;
    System.out.println(elapsedTimeThread);



 }
}
```